# How to print data from list of list with recursion

Tags: python, string, list, recursion, printing

Python. It is given list of list. How to make function which will data from list represent like 'moreline' string' like that every data will be shown in its new line, and in front of it are so many '*' as many as depth of data is.

Example : we have list  `[2, 4, [[3, 8], 1]]` and now function has to make and return string, which function 'print' prints it out like this:

```
* 2
* 4
*** 3
*** 8
** 1
```

I have made for now just this and its not working

```
def Function(List):
    s=''
    Count=0
    for element in List:
        Count+=1
        if type(element)==type([]):
            s+=Function(element)

        else:
            s+=Count*'*'+str(element)+('\n')


    return s
```

if a replace return (s)  with print(s) it report me an error ... but if i return s and than myself print that string it works normally , but once again not how it should

```
>>> Function([2, 4, [[3, 8], 1]])
'*2\n*4\n*3\n*8\n**1\n'
>>> print('*2\n*4\n*3\n*8\n**1\n')
*2
*4
*3
*8
**1
```

Where is the problem, I can't find it. What should I replace, remove, etc.?

Comment: Please do not call your function `Function`, do not call your argument `List` and do not use uppercase for variables...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def r(l, depth=0, ret=[]):
    if isinstance(l,list):
        for i in l:
            r(i, depth+1)
    else:
        ret.append('*' * depth + str(l))
    return ret

print '\n'.join(r([2, 4, [[3, 8], 1]]))
```

output:

```
*2
*4
***3
***8
**1
```

Comment: this is what i need :D but i should print string at the end not every step but just at the end

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass on `count` to recursive calls; local variables do not magically transfer to new function invocations:

```
def format_nested(lst, depth=1):
    s = []
    for element in lst:
        if isinstance(element, list):
            s.append(print_nested(element, depth + 1))
        else:
            s.append('{0} {1}\n'.format(depth * '*', element))
    return ''.join(s)
```

I addressed various other issues with the code:

- Use descriptive function and argument names. `Function` is not a great name.
- Use a list to build up elements of a string, then use `str.join()`; it is faster than building up strings by concatenation.
- Only increment the depth counter when recursing, not for every element in current level of the list.
- Use `isinstance()` to test for specific types.
- String formatting makes it a little easier to build strings together with constant elements, such as a space and a newline.

Demo:

```
>>> format_nested([2, 4, [[3, 8], 1]])
'* 2\n* 4\n*** 3\n*** 8\n** 1\n'
>>> print format_nested([2, 4, [[3, 8], 1]])
* 2
* 4
*** 3
*** 8
** 1
```

Comment: Have yout tried this ? I have copy and pasted it and it doesnt work. Something its wrong with return.

Comment: Yes, I tried it. See the demo. I did correct a small mistake early in the edit cycle, try copying and pasting again.

Comment: i copied again and it passed butt it returned me :
print_nested([2, 4, [[3, 8], 1]])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#76>", line 1, in <module>
    print_nested([2, 4, [[3, 8], 1]])
  File "C:/Python30/b.py", line 7, in print_nested
    s.append('{} {}\n'.format(depth * '*', element))
ValueError: zero length field name in format

Comment: Then you are using Python 2.6, not Python 3 (and `print` is a **statement**, not a function). I'll update.

Comment: actually am using 3.01

Comment: 3.01 is rather ancient by now, you really want to upgrade that to 3.2 at least. 3.3 is the current release, with 3.4 coming out soon (final is slated for February next year).

Comment: @user2471076 3.0 was pretty terrible. In my opinion, the first "proper" Python3 release was 3.1

Comment: @gnibbler: not to mention slow.

Answer (score 0):

Often it's easier to express these things as a generator

```
L = [2, 4, [[3, 8], 1]]

def nest_gen(L):
    if isinstance(L, list):
        for i in L:
            for j in nest_gen(i):
                yield "*"+str(j)
    else:
        yield L

for row in nest_gen(L):
    print(row)
```

In Python3.3+ you can use `yield from`

```
L = [2, 4, [[3, 8], 1]]

def nest_gen(L):
    if isinstance(L, list):
        yield from ("*"+str(j) for i in L for j in nest_gen(i))
    else:
        yield L

for row in nest_gen(L):
    print(row)
```

Instead of catenating strings over and over, you can yield the depth/item as a tuple

```
L = [2, 4, [[3, 8], 1]]

def nest_gen(L):
    if isinstance(L, list):
        yield from ((j+1, k) for i in L for j, k in nest_gen(i))
    else:
        yield 0, L

for item in nest_gen(L):
    print("{:*>{}} {}".format('', *item))
```